# Ordering buttons horizonatally with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, inline

As per a previous question I've run into a bit of a bug laying out some horizontal buttons. Failry certain it has to do with my lack of knowledge on javascript or buttons.

Basically I have list of buttons on a top Nav bar that are supposed to be inline but seem to stack.

Each button simple takes a frame to a different page (yes I'm aware frames are evil but this project needs to render external pages and It suits this purpose http://webdesign.about.com/od/framesprosandcons/a/aaframesyuck.htm)

Anyways. Heres what it looked like when the links were just links and not buttons.

http://s1180.photobucket.com/albums/x406/0vertone/?action=view&current=linkcorrect.jpg

And here is the bugged out version:

http://s1180.photobucket.com/albums/x406/0vertone/?action=view&current=buttonBug.jpg

code for these links as buttons is as follows:

HTML

```
        <ul class = "links">
            <li>
                <!--<a href="http://www.google.ie" target ="content">Test</a>-->
                <form method="link" action="http://www.google.ie" target = "content">
                    <input type="submit" value="google">
                </form>

                |
            </li>
            <li>
                <!--<a href="dashboard.html.erb" target ="content">Dash</a> |-->
                <form method="link" action="http://www.google.ie" target = "content">
                    <input type="submit" value="google">
                </form>

                |
            </li>
            <li>
                <!--<a href="pageview.html.erb" target ="content">Page</a> |-->
                <form method="link" action="http://www.google.ie" target = "content">
                    <input type="submit" value="google">
                </form>

                |
            </li>
            <li>
                <!--<a href="listview.html.erb" target ="content">List</a>-->
                <form method="link" action="http://www.google.ie" target = "content">
                    <input type="submit" value="google">
                </form>

                |
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
        ul li.prev {
            float:left
        }
        .links {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #666;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .links li {
            display: inline;
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
```

Potential solutions would be changing the buttons from javascript to some sort of JQuery UI but Their just simple links. Perhaps theres something missing in my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form` is a block level element hence every form element appears on a row of its own. If one form has two or more buttons then those button *will* appear inline as expected. Try:

```
form {
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: My mistake. I thought if the li that contained the form were inline, it would be inherited. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can display `li` as inline-block elements, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vTjuS/3/)

Answer (score 0):

To make any li horizontal you have to float it. You have to modify .links li

```
.links li{
 padding: 0 5px;
 float: left;
}
```

Please check the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wNYtj/1/)